# Remove whatever between the brackets

Tags: python, regex, registry

As I am working now with windows registries .. I always find the following patterns .. a registry which contains two brackets {} with numbers and letters in between, you can see some examples below:

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Drive\shellex\FolderExtensions\{fbeb8a05-beee-4442-804e-409d6c4515e9}

HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{00BB2763-6A77-11D0-A535-00C04FD7D062}\InProcServer32

HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\MountPoints2\CPC\Volume\{64dcb6fa-03c9-11e6-9e9f-806d6172696f}\
```

Can anyone help me in understanding what does these refer to ? are they generated randomly?

I also tried to parse each registry key and remove whatever between the brackets {} .. as a start, I know this can be done with regular expression but I am really not familiar with them .. any guidance appreciated.

Comment: good question, you deserved my upvote

Comment: Those are CLSIDs (~UUIDs), Windows uses them to identify the classes and interfaces of COM objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you tagged the question with `Python` (tested with `2.7`):

```
import re

string = """
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Drive\shellex\FolderExtensions\{fbeb8a05-beee-4442-804e-409d6c4515e9}
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{00BB2763-6A77-11D0-A535-00C04FD7D062}\InProcServer32
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\MountPoints2\CPC\Volume\{64dcb6fa-03c9-11e6-9e9f-806d6172696f}
"""

rx = r'\{[^}]+\}\\?'
string = re.sub(rx, '', string)
print string
```

The snippet gives you all keys without curly braces. Thanks to @Liam for pointing out an error before.
*Hint:* I am a Mac User, however, I'm pretty sure the braces are somewhat needed, aren't they?

Comment: sometimes it outputs a double backslash (`HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\\InProcServer32`)

Answer (score 1):

replace `{.*?}` with `{}` (lazy dot in case two GUIDS on one line)

[<kbd>demo</kbd>](https://regex101.com/r/nB8tG7/4)

The strings are [Globally Unique Identifiers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Globally_unique_identifier). from [here](https://www.guidgenerator.com/online-guid-generator.aspx):

> GUID (or UUID) is an acronym for 'Globally Unique Identifier' (or
>   'Universally Unique Identifier'). It is a 128-bit integer number used
>   to identify resources. The term GUID is generally used by developers
>   working with Microsoft technologies, while UUID is used everywhere
>   else.
>
> 128-bits is big enough and the generation algorithm is unique enough
>   that if 1,000,000,000 GUIDs per second were generated for 1 year the
>   probability of a duplicate would be only 50%. Or if every human on
>   Earth generated 600,000,000 GUIDs there would only be a 50%
>   probability of a duplicate.
>
> GUIDs are used in enterprise software development in C#, Java, and C++
>   as database keys, component identifiers, or just about anywhere else a
>   truly unique identifier is required. GUIDs are also used to identify
>   all interfaces and objects in COM programming.

Answer (score 0):

Regex is the best fit in this case. Just use:

```
import re
string = 'HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{00BB2763-6A77-11D0-A535-00C04FD7D062}\InProcServer32'
string = re.sub('{(.+)}', '', string)
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like this?

```
string = "HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{00BB2763-6A77-11D0-A535-00C04FD7D062}\InProcServer32"

cleared_string = string[:string.index("{")+1]+string[string.index("}"):]

print cleared_string
```

Comment: That doesn't work.  It shows all but the string wanted. Change to `>>> cleared_string = string[string.index("{")+1:string.index("}")]
`